# Paperclip with rails 3.1 error with routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

So I've followed the instructions here: http://doganberktas.com/2010/09/14/amazon-s3-and-paperclip-rails-3/

In my profile model I have:

```
  attr_accessor  :pic_file_name (this was requested on first attempt)
  has_attached_file :pic,
       :styles => {
       :thumb=> "100x100#",
       :small  => "400x400>" },
     :storage => :s3,
     :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml",
     :path => "/:style/:id/:filename"
```

I have resources :profiles in my routes.

my view has the following:

```
<%= form_for :profile, @profile, :url => profile_path, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
<%= f.file_field :pic %>
<%= f.submit :class => "button-style", :value => "Upload File" %>
<% end %>
```

When I view the page, I get this error: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"profiles"}. Although I can assure you, I have a profiles controller with a show action.

If I change the view to

```
<%= form_for :profile, @profile, :url => @profile, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
<%= f.file_field :pic %>
<%= f.submit :class => "button-style", :value => "Upload File" %>
<% end %>
```

It tells me I have the wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)

Then if I change the view to

```
<%= form_for @profile, :url => profile_path, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
<%= f.file_field :pic %>
<%= f.submit :class => "button-style", :value => "Upload File" %>
<% end %>
```

The page loads, and I can upload an image. However trying to print it later using:

<%= current_user.profile.pic %> gives me: /pics/original/missing.png (as does profile.pic.url)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems beyond stupid (as the above has worked for me before) - but this fixed it:

changing the view to:

```
<%= form_for(@profile, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the solution. Incidentally,

```
<%= form_for (@profile, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
```

Didn't work for me, but

```
<%= form_for(@profile, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
```

Did work. That space I had after the `form_for` appears to break things and may have been the cause of my problems.

Comment: This calls `m` with two arguments: `m(a, b)`. This is a syntax error since the parentheses will be considered to group `a, b` into a single (invalid) expression: `m (a, b)`.